# Algorithm for generating Kakeya Sets in Finite Fields

Tags: geometry, finite-fields, kakeya-sets

I am searching for an implementation of generating Kakeya Sets in Finite fields as defined in Dvirs
[proof of the finite field kakeya conjecture](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Ezdvir/papers/Dvir09.pdf).
I search for an implementation, which gives me precisely the points of the Kakeya set $ K \subset \mathbb{F}^n_q$ as listed like the following:
$ K = \{ (1,2),(0,2),\dots \}$

EDIT:
so by $ K = \{ \dots \} $ I mean the points, lets call them $p$, for which the following holds: $ p \in K $

So and to answer Jean Marie's question. I will now construct a Kakeya Set for $\mathbb{F}^2_3$ this is by far easy and an amusement to build.

Ok, we know, there are $4$ directional vectors mainly because of the fact, that for the number of vectors, lets call them $n_v$, holds the following equation:
$n_v = \frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$. Ok lets call the Set of vectors: $N_v$ and define them: $N_v = \{(0,1)^T,(1,0)^T,(1,1)^T,(1,2)^T\}$ Note, that we are in $\mathbb{F_3}$

Therefore (I assume, that you all know how to construct such simple example) the Kakeya Set $K \subset \mathbb{F}^n_q$ is (also now we will write down the points of this set and not explicit the lines (because I am interested in the points) as we would see the lattice of points as a "cartesian system" (I hope you know what I mean with this)) $K = \{(1,0),(2,0),(0,1),(1,1),(2,0),(2,1)\}$ which is only one possibility of a Kakeya Set.

So what I am now really interested in is an algorithm, which already exists (if not I have to implement one myself), so that I get the points of my generated Kakeya Set.

Thanks for your help and I hope you understand now even if my english is not the best.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What do you mean by (1,2) for example ? Hopefully the line joining point 1 to point 2 ? Say how you "label/rank" your points ; is point 2 for example associated with (2,0,...0) ?

Comment: Show you have worked on your issue by attempting to produce a Kakeya set for $q=3^2$ and $n=3$ for example...

Comment: Hello Jean Marie, I hope that you now know what I wrongly described.... excuse me for that informal error

Answer (score 0):

For fields of prime orders (this is far from optimal, doing a lot of redundant checks):

```
import itertools

q = 3 # size of field
n = 3 # dimension of vector space

def line(b, m):
    return set(tuple((bi + t*mi)%q for bi, mi in zip(b, m)) for t in range(q))

def is_kakeya(K, Fnq):
    for m in Fnq:
        for b in Fnq:
            if K.issuperset(line(b, m)):
                break
        else:
            return False
    return True

Fnq = set(itertools.product(range(q), repeat=n)) # vector space F_n^q

for K_len in range(len(Fnq)-1, 0, -1):
    print(f'{q}, {n}, {K_len} / {len(Fnq)}')
    for K in itertools.combinations(Fnq, K_len):
        K = set(K)
        if is_kakeya(K, Fnq):
            print(f'{(q,n,K_len)} - {K}')
            break
    else:
        break
```

Slightly faster/better version: [finite_kakeya.py](https://github.com/idanpa/finite_kakeya/blob/main/finite_kakeya.py)